# cannot use match_parent in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am following a tutorial about Android. The very first tutorial consists in placing a text and setting `layout_height` to `match_parent` like this (screenshot from tutorial) :

[image]

However, when I try to do the same with the latest version of Android studio, this option is not proposed. I only have the choice between `wrap_content` and `match_constraint`. But if I go to the XML view and enter the value manually, it works just fine.

Screenshot from my editor :
[image]

Why? Is this a bug? Or is `match_parent` deprecated?

Also, I have an error message which can be related

> Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

[image]

Comment: People told me (witihout link sources) that for ConstraintLayout match_parent is replaced with 0dp only, other components do offers match_parent as a value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [the `ConstraintLayout` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html):

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".

So, I would consider the Android Studio change to be a further "nudge" to stop using `match_parent` with `ConstraintLayout`. Frankly, I never had much luck with it working when I tried it. `match_parent` has its uses with classic container classes (e.g., `LinearLayout`) or for the size of the `ConstraintLayout` itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are working on a Constraint Layout. 
If your xml Layout was Linear or Relative you would have the option.
Check your xml file to see what i am refering to.

You will see something like that.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Change the Layout and you will be able to match_parent